# Scapy get the actual value of a field

Tags: python, scapy

this question is related to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692411/scapy-bitfield-and-type-question)

I would like to check the value of a Field in scapy:

```
def compute(fields):
    print fields
    print fields[1].name
    print fields[1].size
    print fields[1].default
    return 23


class Foo(Packet):
    array=[ 
           BitField("foo",0x0,2),
           BitField("foo1",0x0,2),
           BitField("bar",0x0,2),
           BitField("blub",None,2)
           ]


    def post_build(self, p, pay):
          print dir(self.array[1])
          res = compute(self.array)
          p = struct.pack(">b", res)
          return p

if __name__ == "__main__":
     interact(mydict=globals(), mybanner="")
```

The code is not entirly working, but the important parts are. The output is:

```
[<Field ().foo>, <Field ().foo1>, <Field ().bar>, <Field ().blub>]
foo1
2
0
```

Now, the problem is when I change a value on the commandline:

```
>>> a=Foo()
>>> a.foo1=0x23
>>> a.show2()
```

How can I find out (in my compute method) what value foo1 has? I think this is not really a difficult question, but I cannot figure out what I'm missing here :/ Would be cool if you could give me a hand :)

With best regards

Answer (score 0):

From the command line (or in code where you declare a Scapy layer) you access a Scapy layer and a field like so:

```
>>> a=Foo()
>>> a[Foo].foo1 = 0x23
```

Does this answer your question?  If not, explain what exactly the purpose of your compute() function is and I will edit this answer.